# Is it possible to feed a Danfojs Series object to D3js data() binding method?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observable, danfojs

I created a Series object from my data, like so:
[image]

But I don't know how to actually implement the Series object to scale and bind the data, here is my code:

```js
function render(svg) {
  //   const xValue = d => d['Population (2020)'];
  //   const yValue = d => d['Country (or dependency)'];

  //   const xExtent = d3.extent(world_population, xValue);
  //   const xScale = d3
  //     .scaleLinear()
  //     .domain(xExtent)
  //     .range([0, width]);

  //   const yScale = d3
  //     .scaleBand()
  //     .domain(world_population.map(yValue))
  //     .range([0, height]);

  const xValue = d => d.data;
  const yValue = d => d.index;

  const xExtent = d3.extent(plot_data.values);
  const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(xExtent)
    .range([0, width]);

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(plot_data.index)
    .range([0, height]);

  const selection = d3.select(svg);
  selection
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(plot_data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('fill', 'slateblue')
    .attr('y', d => yScale(d.index))
    .attr('width', d => xScale(d.data))
    .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth());
}
```

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real question here is about your data structure: how to switch to a more convenient one for D3.js purposes?

As you highlighted, we have keys in `plot_data.index_arr`, and data in `plot_data.data`.

By doing a `map` over `index_arr` we get the indexes.
The second argument to the callback `i` is the index which we can use to get the data, by accessing `plot_data.data[i]`.

```
newData = plot_data.index_arr.map((d,i) => [d, plot_data.data[i]])
```

Once done, we can put them however we want: here I put them in an array, but you can put them in a {key:value} object or a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map).

```js
plot_data={
  index_arr:['a',"b", "c"],
  data:[1,2,3]
}
console.log(plot_data.index_arr.map((d,i) => [d, plot_data.data[i]]))
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, thank you for your suggestion, I created an array of objects in the end following your advise and I got it working, but I don't know if it is worth the hassle to be honest, at least I learned something out of it

Comment: I think the hassle can be worth it because the data structure is easier to use. However, if you need to be consistent, then it might not be worth it and go with using the Danfojs object directly.